# PushNotification Not Working

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have been killing an application from Background. Then Push notification comes in and it is shown on my notification tray. When I tap on notification, my code works fine. When I am not clicking on notification and simply launch the application. How we get notification userinfo. I am stuck . Please help.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window=[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    NSDictionary* userInfo =
    [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    NSLog(@"%@",userInfo);
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    NSLog(@"%@",userInfo);

}
```

Comment: What did you try? Can you provide us with some code?

Comment: Where you struck ? what you are trying to do? you didn't stated you problem properly

Comment: @Imran i want my notification info when my app kill from background. and i am launching an app without clicking notification.

Comment: You can't access it. Think of it as you won't have notification always so it doesn't make sense you need notification info even when user didn't click it.
In this case just launch your app normally as of there wasn't any notification .

Answer (score 1):

In simple words, you cant access the `userInfo` of your notification, when you directly tap on your App icon, you will only get it when you tap on the Notification in Notification Bar.

Comment: How we overcome this. Is there any alternative for doing this .

Comment: You can keep a flag for read and unread messages in your server and query it when you launch the app. If you have unread messages show the user when launched. That's the only solution

Comment: @MahimaTyagi You will manage this with the help from your server side.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the information from a notification if the app is not directly launched by means of tapping the notification. That being sad, you could check with your remote server for unread notifications when starting the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the notification object if you are directly tapping on the app icon, you will only receive information about the notification that was used to open your app. So if a user opens your app, and your app has notifications, you will not be able to retrieve them from with in your app.

You can track the notification on a server and fetch the unread notification from the server when the user launch it directly from the app icon. Thus the server keeps track of all the notification. This is how Facebook does it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the information of the notification unless you open your application through the push notification.